# Attempting to install electron, getting a code EEXIST though for some reason?

Tags: node.js, npm

npm ERR! code EEXIST

npm ERR! syscall mkdir

npm ERR! path C:\Users(my name deleted...obviously\AppData\Roaming\npm

npm ERR! errno -4075

npm ERR! EEXIST: file already exists, mkdir 'C:\Users\again\AppData\Roaming\npm'

npm ERR! File exists: C:\Users\again\AppData\Roaming\npm

npm ERR! Remove the existing file and try again, or run npm

npm ERR! with --force to overwrite files recklessly.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\again\AppData\Local\npm-cache_logs\2023-11-21T06_36_51_303Z-debug-0.log